# I am currently having an issue with PHP Fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently having an issue with wordpress that occurred after i completed the recent update.

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/shreejifilters/public_html/wp-config.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php73/usr/share/pear') in /home/shreejifilters/public_html/wp-load.php on line 37

Comment: `/home/shreejifilters/public_html/wp-config.php` probably doesn't exist or php doesn't have rights to read it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Change the file permission of wp_config. It should be in 644